# Need help with Function operations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

What is the domain of $g(f(x))$ when given $f(x)=2x^{1/2}$ , $g(x) = 9x^2$ and why? It would be appreciated if someone could explain.

Comment: This question has no answer as written. Even assuming you meant "what is the largest (in some unspecified sense) domain for which $g\circ f$ is a well-defined function," depending on what is meant by $x^{1/2}$, possible answers include all of $\mathbb{C}$, all of $\mathbb{R}$, all nonnegative numbers, all perfect squares, ...

Answer (score 1):

When you write $g(f(x))$ what you mean is you are going to "feed" $x$ to $f$ and take the result and feed it to $g$. Now $g$ can accept any number, so it will not impose any restrictions. However, $f$ can only accept non-negative numbers (I am assuming you are working in the field of reals). Thus $g(f(\cdot))$ can only accept non-negative numbers. So the domain is 
$$
\left\{ x | x\ge 0\right\}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Think of the domain of the function as the set of values that you can meaningfully plug into the function. Now, $f(x)=2x^{1/2}$, so, you can't plug negative numbers in the formula for f, right?

Can you continue now?

Comment: So would you look at g(x) at all if you wanted to find the domain of g(f(x))? Otherwise i would say 2sqrt(x) Domain {x|x>0}.

Comment: The function that you are looking is now g composed with f. If you can't plug some numbers in the formula for f, you certainly can;t make sense of $g(f(x))$. So the domain would be a subset of the set you have written. Now, is it equal to the set that you have written? That depends on what numbers can we plug into g. Do you need more hints?